# to_tsquery for postgresql formatting

Tags: postgresql

I've searched the [postgreSQL documentation (on v9.6)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/index.html) for use of to_tsquery() as well as a number of other sources (via the Google search engine). I have found [hints](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CA%2BKJVfyWmhcBW-ajgKY%2BD1qFbaYqL4fDvF_aME-RH0_RNzvN9Q%40mail.gmail.com) of others experiencing similar problems, but I could use help perhaps just understanding the fundamental nature of the to_tsquery postgreSQL syntax.

if I query

```sql
SELECT * from table
WHERE table.email @@ to_tsquery('user@domain.ext');
```

then I get all rows where the `email` column contains 'user@domain.ext'.

But if I query

```sql
SELECT * from table
WHERE table.email @@ to_tsquery('user:* & domain:* & ext:*');
```

then I get no rows.

Can anyone offer any guidance on how I may be misusing `to_tsquery` in the second case? My intention is to simply drop `@` and `.` from the email address and MATCH on the cases where `usr`, `domain`, and `ext` match the email.

Thank you for any guidance!

--J

Answer (score 0):

As the PostgreSQL committer replied in the [discussion](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CA%2BKJVfyWmhcBW-ajgKY%2BD1qFbaYqL4fDvF_aME-RH0_RNzvN9Q%40mail.gmail.com) you linked to:

> tsvector is meant for searching for natural-language words. It is not
>   a good idea to imagine that it works exactly like a substring match,
>   especially on strings that aren't simple words.

The text search parser recognizes `user@domain.ext` in a larger text as a token of type `email`. It doesn't provide any function to extract the top-level domain or sub-domains or local address part.

Besides, it's not clear what's your use case. Matching a locale part against prefix might make sense, but matching a top level domain against a prefix? `.co` as a TLD hasn't any more to do with `.com` than with `.org` or `.info`, so `ext:*` is not going to achieve much as match pattern.

Also subdomains are hierarchical in nature. `ibm` can be found in `something.ibm.com`, which doesn't match `ibm:*` , so that kind of match doesn't appear very useful either.